# Why is clicking on the slider element not picking the right value in Firefox and IE?

Tags: html, selenium, slider

I have a slider control on a webpage that I am attempting to test via Selenium. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="slider theme1 ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-action="Slider" data-step="True" data-input="CurrentGoalValue">
    <div class="slider-main">
        <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active" style="top: 35%; left: 25%;"></span>
        <ul>
            <li data-val="0" style="left: 0%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item">7</li>
            <li data-val="12.5" style="left: 12.5%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">8</li>
            <li data-val="25" style="left: 25%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">9</li>
            <li data-val="37.5" style="left: 37.5%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">10</li>
            <li data-val="50" style="left: 50%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item">11</li>
            <li data-val="62.5" style="left: 62.5%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">12</li>
            <li data-val="75" style="left: 75%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">13</li>
            <li data-val="87.5" style="left: 87.5%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item ">14</li>
            <li data-val="100" style="left: 100%; width: 12.5%;" class="slider-item">15</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For my test, I find the appropriate `<li>` item and invoke Click on it to simulate the user clicking on the numbers (I have another test where I test clicking in between). Weirdly enough, the "7" value is consistently failing, with clicking on it instead producing a value of "8". This seems like odd behavior to me. Does anyone know why it might be acting like that?

Here is my Selenium code to select a given item:

```
IWebElement sliderValue = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//li[normalize-space(@class)='slider-item' and text()='" + Days.ToString() + "']")));

if (sliderValue != null)
{
   sliderValue.Click();
}
else
{
   Assert.Fail(String.Format("No slider value was available for {0}.", Days));
}
```

My initial guess was that the testing framework was clicking on the far edge of the element, but the documentation indicates differently, that clicks originate in the center of elements.

I don't have this issue with the Chrome driver weirdly enough, just Firefox and IE. And, just to be clear, it works fine on the webpage itself where clicking on those numbers selects the correct number, even for the lowest value one.

Comment: Hi there, can youplease show us your code ? It would be much easier to find the fault this way

Comment: I have added the Selenium test case code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer and the solution. The list items being used to indicate the positions on the slider span the entire distance from the number to the beginning of the next number. The default location for clicking is in the center. A centerline click rounds up to the next number. The following code was used for the clicks so as to click just left of center (insert political joke) and the issue goes away:

```
Actions clicker = new Actions(Driver);
clicker.MoveToElement(sliderValue).MoveByOffset(-5, 0).Click().Perform();
```